# PyQt5 QMYSQL Driver not loaded

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, qsqldatabase

I know there a many questions and answers on SO for this question, but nothing worked for me.

I installed the newest `QT Creator 4.9.2` with `Qt 5.13.0` `MinGW 32-Bit` and `MySQLServer 5.5` to compile the `QMYSQL` driver. I but the driver in the `sqldrivers` folder and the `libmysql.dll` in the bin folder.

If I use C++ to connect to the database, everything is working fine, but I doesn't with python.

Additionally I installed on a fresh Python 3.7 32-Bit:

- PyQt5: `pip install pyqt5 (5.13.0)`
- mysqlclient: `pip install mysqlclient (1.4.2)`
- mysql-connector: `pip install mysql-connector (2.2.9)`

and but the driver I compiled before in the sqldrivers folder from PyQt5, because the driver was missing there as well.

My Class:

```
class SqlConnector(QSqlDatabase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SqlConnector, self).__init__()
        self.db = self.connect()

    def __del__(self):
        self.db.close()

    def connect(self):
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        db.setHostName("hostname")
        db.setDatabaseName("database")
        db.setUserName("username")
        db.setPassword("1234567890")

        ok = db.open()

        if ok:
            print("Connection established")
            return db
        else:
            print("Connection failed: ", db.lastError().text())
            return None

    def getPools(self):
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT id, name, token, dlxCode FROM AnalysisPool", self.db)

        model = QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery(query)

        return model
```

Main Method:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQueryModel, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    poolView = QTableView()
    poolView.show()

    database = SqlConnector()

    # poolView.setModel(database.getPools())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The libraryPaths from PyQt are `C:/Python/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins` and `C:/Python`

The used OS is `Windows 10 (1809) 64-Bit` and I included in the path variable the MySQLServer lib folder.

I don't know what to do, I have read every SO question about this topic without a working solution for my problem.

Comment: what is the output of  `print(QtCore.QCoreApplication.libraryPaths())`?

Comment: @eyllanesc The output is `['C:/Python/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins', 'C:/Python']`

Comment: try copying `libmysql.dll` to `C:/Python/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers`

Comment: Nothing changed, I get the same error again. The driver was not loaded.

Comment: on Linux I had to copy `libqsqlmysql.so` (similar to `libmysql.dll` on Windows) to this folder - and `PyQt` could find it but it still couldn't load it. I found in other question that using `ldd libqsqlmysql.so` I can see want other libraries it needs to work and I found I need also `libmysqlclient.so.18` which is part of `MySQL`, not `PyQt` - I had only `libmysqlclient.so.20`. After installing correct version it works for me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this way: UNinstall package insraled via pip3.
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
Install the native package for your distro (linux case). In my case is Fedora then
Sudo dnf install python3-qt5 python3-qt5-qtbase --allowerasing
Use an option wich lets you overwrite old files like --force or --allowerasing or something equivalent